# Having problems with setting up php mail() on Plesk

Tags: php, forms, email, plesk

I'm setting up an email form for a website and the mail() function just refuses to work. The server's running Plesk. I'm sure the code's fine, as it runs without a problem on a different web server.

I've set up a no-reply email account and added the from header, but that still didn't fix the issue. Here's my code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name, $email \nMessage: $message";
$to = "myemail@differentdomain.com";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$headers = 'From: noreply@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: $email' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $formcontent, $headers);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Ilian

Comment: where does `phpversion()` come into play? Isn't that a function? Seems like there's nothing calling it after, probably stops dead in its tracks because of it. Not 100% sure about it though.

Comment: It is, it just makes sure the headers are passed properly. Really doesn't make much of a difference though, with it or without it, it still wouldn't send anything.

Comment: Like you said, your code is fine, can't think why it wouldn't work.

Comment: did you check the return value from `mail()`? if it's boolean true, then PHP handed the email over to your server's SMTA successfully, and the problem isn't in PHP. You should never assume success when dealing with external resources.

Comment: May be nothing but did you check your `php.ini` as to what/where your Mail path is? Also check if your Mail is `activated` under your Mail Server Settings.

Comment: Yeah, it's true, it does execute mail(). Where could the problem be then?

Comment: @Fred Yeah, I had a look at those and I believe Mail is activated.

Fred Wuerges, I'll check this out, thanks.

Comment: @FredWuerges this doesn't seem to work either, although it says it sends the message. :(

Answer (score 0):

The code itself isn't enough to judge. Sending mail would depend on

1. PHP code (it seems ok)
2. PHP config (it is unknown). PHP on your server can be configured to send through command line (sendmail tool) or through SMTP. More details can be learned from description of mail() function in PHP docs
3. Setup MTA (unknown) - i.e. authentication mode in remote SMTP OR availability of local unauthorized delivery via sendmail tool (which might be blocked to prevent sending spam)
4. In case of remote SMTP connection availability of mail server would be important

I would recommend checking all stages.The code itself is just one of many factors
 when network communication is involved.

Comment: Hi, I will check those things. The really weird part about it is that most emails do go through.. but with a serious delay, sometimes even more than 10 hours.

Comment: From my perspective it proofs you code ok and PHP config ok, but MTA configuration seems strange.

Comment: hmm okay, thanks for that. I'll try to get in touch with the company and see what they say about it.